# Как узнать код нажатой клавиши в хуке (ловушке)?

Tags: winapi, hook, delphi

Здравствуйте!

Вот имеется функция обработки хука на клавитуру:

```
function KeyboardProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: wParam; lParam:lParam ): LParam; stdcall;

begin
messagebeep(1000,100);  //for example
end;
```

А как можно обработать нажатую клавишу и заставить пикнуть динамик по нажатию на определенную клавишу? Например, на "1" или "2". Пытался все это сделать с помощью

```
GetAsyncKeyState
```

и

```
GetKeyState
```

Но вышла полная ерунда, ведь первая функция определяет состояние не в текущий момент а за все время работы (грубо говоря). Так как можно получить код клавиши в хуке? Спасибо!

Comment: @Asen Когда форматируете код, не надо добавлять знак цитирования > в начале строки, достаточно 4 пробелов или табуляции.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - прочитайте внимательно документацию по `KeyboardProc` (MSDN)

> `wParam [in] 
> Type: WPARAM`
>
> The virtual-key code of the key that generated the keystroke message.

- из wParam и берите код клавиши...

Comment: Так не работает. Получилось сделать с помощью структуры PMsg.

Comment: @0xFFh: Может, напишите канонический ответ и примете его? Для будущих поколений.